# Tasks Not Valid for Deploy Job in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines

I'm currently encountering an issue with my Azure Pipelines setup. When I attempt to run my pipeline, I receive the following error message:

```
"Tasks with versions 'Add release annotation to Azure Application Insights resource...:1., Generate release notes:2.' are not valid for deploy job 'Run on agent' in stage PRP."
```

I've checked and these tasks are available in the versions specified, but they're not being recognized as valid for the deployment job in my stage.

If anyone has encountered this issue before or has any suggestions on how to resolve it, your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

I tried everything to solve it but still blocked please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That task is deprecated. Microsoft recommends using the Azure cli or Azure PowerShell directly instead:

> ### Note
>
> If you're still using the Application Insights annotation deployment task, you should delete it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/annotations#create-release-annotations-with-the-azure-cli